# Download link for SP.Search.js

Tags: javascript, spservices, jsom, download, keywordquery

I going to create Keyword search using JSOM. So i want some reference files to accomplish this. Please share the download link for the below files

- SP.Search.js
- SP.RequestExecutor.js
- SP.runtime.debug.js

Please refer the link for Source : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/jsom-keyword-query-search-in-sharepoint/

Comment: download directly from the browser using the url in the format /_layouts/15/sp.debug.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on tutorial , I think you don't need to have a copy from the above files because it will be uploaded inside SharePoint , So if you need the mentioned code at tutorial work, try to use the following script instead script tag references

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
        //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order.  
         $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                    function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js",
                    function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.search.js", executeSearch);

                    });
                  });
              });
               });
    // **add your code from tutorial start from executeSearch search**
    </script>
```

But if you need a copy , try the suggestion from @Aveenav

- Open the file as the following `http://rootsite/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js`
- create a new file with the same name and extension (`ie:SP.runtime.debug.js`)
- Copy and paste the code within it.

[image]